# Callbacks with D3

Tags: javascript, callback, d3.js

I'm using the [D3](http://d3js.org/) javascript library to dynamically change line thicknesses. What I want to achieve is a line that increase in thickness, and decreases in thickness, repeatedly constantly. To draw a line, I used the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  
    <div id="D3line"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">

            var lineSVG = d3.select("#D3line")  
                .append("svg:svg")
                .attr("width", 500)  
                .attr("height", 200);               

            var myLine = lineSVG.append("svg:line")
                .attr("x1", 60)
                .attr("y1", 60)
                .attr("x2", 450)
                .attr("y2", 150)
                .style("stroke", "rgb(6,120,155)")
                .style("stroke-opacity", 2);                


            </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then, to change the line stroke thickness, I used the following code:

```
var lines = lineSVG.selectAll("line")   // select all lines 

function makeLinesThick()
{
    lines.transition().duration(500)
    .style("stroke-width", "5")
    .each("end", makeLinesThin);
}

function makeLinesThin(){
    lines.transition().duration(500)
    .style("stroke-width", "2")
    .each("end", makeLinesThick);
}

// call function to change lines
makeLinesThick()
```

However, I end up with this not running properly and getting an 'Unresponsive script' message in my browser. I'm not sure if I am structuring the callbacks properly in this case.

Edit: I changed my incorrect callback handling by removing the `()` in the `.each()` line.

Comment: I'm not familiar with d3, but in the `.each()` blocks, are you calling the opposite function within the `.each()`? Maybe that works differently in d3 than jQuery, but in jQuery, that would presumably create a recurring call/inverse call loop. If that's meant to pass a callback handler, take the `()` off so you pass a reference instead of calling the function, e.g.: `.each("end", makeLinesThick)`

Comment: Yes, I'm calling the opposite function within each `.each()`. I was trying to pass a callback handler. I took the `()` away (good to learn how to do it properly!), but I still get an unresponsive script error.

Comment: @JaredFarrish that would be infinite recursion regardless of what `.each` does because `.each` is never even called

Comment: @Esailija - I guess I don't quite follow you.

Comment: @JaredFarrish see: http://jsfiddle.net/zWHYf/ it doesn't matter what `.asd` does or if it even exists.

Comment: @Esailija - FYI, that fiddle crashes Firefox (but not Chrome). You're making the same point I made in the second half of that first comment; my point was I'm not familiar with d3.js and it's `.each` insofar if you can pass handlers like that to event listeners. I'm skeptical to say the least.

Comment: @JaredFarrish My point was that it doesn't matter if it's jQuery or d3 because `.each` is not called. It seems you are thinking that libraries somehow mutate the language's standard semantics so I wanted to correct that, just trying to help :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `.each("end", ...)` is called for *every* element that you're selecting. That is, `makeLinesThin` is called once for each line in `makeLinesThick`. This is what causes your browser to hang.

There are several ways you could make it work. You could change your code to do the transitions for each line individually (see the documentation for [`transition.each()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-each)) or you could schedule the transitions on all lines separately using `settimeout()`. Note in particular the documentation for [`transition.transition()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-transition) -- you can schedule another transition before the current one is complete.

You might also want to have a look at [`d3.timer()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-d3_timer), example [here](http://www.jasondavies.com/animated-bezier/).

Answer (score 1):

use .each("start") and .each("end") to set your transitions

Answer (score 0):

```
var mutateLine =
    function(line, t, width, altWidth) {
        d3.select(line).transition().duration(t).style("stroke-width", width)
        .each("end", function() {
            if ( mutateLine ) mutateLine(line, t, altWidth, width);
        });
    }

// assumes lines is obtained from d3.selectAll()
var mutateLines =
    function(lines, t, width, altWidth) {
        if ( !mutateLine)
            return;
        lines[0].forEach(function(line) {
            mutateLine(line, t, width, altWidth);
        }
    };

// start mutating
mutateLines(lines, 500, 5, 2);

// stop mutating
mutateLine = null;
```

Comment: Like Lars said, you cannot use each like that.  This way is safer because you're handling each line separately, and you don't need to rely on timers.  You can stop and resume this way, too.